# trying to print second level array in an array using while loop, while getting query from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, while-loop

I feel like banging my head now. I can't solve it.. doesn't make sense.

```
$sql = "SELECT x,y FROM datapoints ";
$result = $conn->query($sql) ;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $dataPoints = array(
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array("x" => $row["x"], "y" => $row["y"])   
            if  ($result->num_rows > 1) { 
                echo ",";
            }
        }  
    );
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I'm getting this error for this code

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ')'

My expected out put is as follows

```
$dataPoints = array(
    array("x" => 800, "y" => 350),
    array("x" => 900, "y" => 450),
    array("x" => 850, "y" => 450),
    array("x" => 1250, "y" => 700),
    array("x" => 1100, "y" => 650),
    array("x" => 1350, "y" => 850),
    array("x" => 1200, "y" => 900),
    array("x" => 1410, "y" => 1250),
    array("x" => 1250, "y" => 1100),
    array("x" => 1400, "y" => 1150),
    array("x" => 1500, "y" => 1050),
    array("x" => 1330, "y" => 1120),
    array("x" => 1580, "y" => 1220),
    array("x" => 1620, "y" => 1400),
    array("x" => 1250, "y" => 1450),
    array("x" => 1350, "y" => 1600),
    array("x" => 1650, "y" => 1300),
    array("x" => 1700, "y" => 1620),
    array("x" => 1750, "y" => 1700),
    array("x" => 1830, "y" => 1800),
    array("x" => 1900, "y" => 2000),
    array("x" => 2050, "y" => 2200),
    array("x" => 2150, "y" => 1960),
    array("x" => 1750, "y" => 1750),
    array("x" => 1830, "y" => 1800),
    array("x" => 1900, "y" => 2000),
    array("x" => 2050, "y" => 2200),
    array("x" => 2150, "y" => 1960),
    array("x" => 2250, "y" => 1990)
);
```

Comment: you just cannot have a while loop inside an array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you:

$sql = "SELECT x,y FROM datapoints ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $dataPoints[] = array("x" => $row["x"], "y" => $row["y"]);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. this worked!!! but I was wondering why my one didn't work? is saying array and $dataPoints[] , not the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
$sql = "SELECT x,y FROM datapoints ";
$result = $conn->query($sql) ;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $dataPoints = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataPoints[] = array("x" => $row["x"], "y" => $row["y"]);
    }
    print_r($dataPoints);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: maybe add a `print_r($dataPoints)` at the end, so that there is the desired output